# External HDD wont format to full size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate 3TB external hard drive, I accidentally formatted it when creating a bootable USB using power ISO. When attempting to reformat it back to the default NTFS, it cannot be formatted to the full 3TB it maxes out at 2TB leaving some space unallocated. How can I get the full 3TB without having to create two partitions

I have tried using the using `diskpart` to clean and reformat the hard drive without success
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Right click in the area where it says "disk 1" and select convert to GPT.

Comment: Glad to hear, I was just posting a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you used to format the disk apparently partitioned the disk as MBR rather than GPT.

Aside from the reasonably well known "4 primary partitions" limit for MBR it is also limited to around 2TB for the disk.

You need to repartition the disk using GPT. You should be able to right click the "Disk 1" area and select "convert to GPT"

That should then let you use the whole disk.